# Generate a report off of a query in Access using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using Microsoft Access. I have a SQL Query. `Select * from people`

I have current code which is hooked to a form button. How could I fix my code to properly generate a report?

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "PeopleSearch", acViewPreview 'open query
DoCmd.SelectObject acQuery, "PeopleSearch" 
RunCommand acGenerateReport
```

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? It's sad that you can't provide feedback as I won't be able to learn from anything to improve myself in the future.

Comment: this down-vote has not come from me as I gave you an up-vote for a clear understandable question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are really close. Here is an example on how it is done. Also, I've closed out of the query at the end of the report generation.

```
Private Sub Command24_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command24_Click

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "PeopleSearch", acViewPreview
    DoCmd.SelectObject acQuery, "PeopleSearch"
    RunCommand acCmdNewObjectAutoReport
    DoCmd.Close acQuery, "PeopleSearch"

Exit_Command24_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_Command24_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Command24_Click

End Sub
```